# Python Multiprocessing Performance Impacted by Loading Data to Ram

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am using the Python Multiprocessing module to parallize a task, but have noticed that depending on how much data I load to instance attributes, the time of execution varies.  In the below code, self.pg_data_download_run() multiprocesses a function.  It takes 2.6 seconds the first time it is run when no data is loaded to RAM.  However, the time to execution changes:

```python
self.pg_data_download_run()

for symbol in self.tradeable_universe_symbol_list:
    self.data_day[symbol] = pd.read_csv(self.data_dir_day + symbol + '.csv')

self.pg_data_download_run()
```

1. After I load 20 dataframes with a RAM impact of 10 MB it takes 3.2 seconds.
2. After I load 51 dataframes witha a RAM impact of 21 MB it takes 5.5 seconds.

It seems that the time of execution is correlated to the size of object being assigned to RAM, but I cannot see why such a small RAM impact has such a drastic decrease of performance.  I have 4 GB available RAM on this machine.  What is causing the performance degradation?

---

EDIT:  I have made dummy functions to help replicate this error.  Running multiprocessing_speed_test causes multiprocessing_test_run to run in 10 seconds the first time and 30 seconds the second time after some dataframes are loaded.

```python
def multiprocessing_test_run(self):

    print('multiprocess testing')
    iterations = 200
    iterations = [x for x in range(iterations)]
    tstart = dt.datetime.now()

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count() - 1) as executor:
        executor.map(self.multiprocessing_test, iterations)

    # sleep for half a second, so 0.5 * iterations is the time it takes with one thread.  Divide by actual time to
    # get the multiprocessing multiplier
    print('Duration (s): ', (dt.datetime.now() - tstart).seconds)

def multiprocessing_test(self, iteration):

    print("Iteration Number: ", str(iteration))
    time.sleep(0.5)

def multiprocessing_speed_test(self, data_dir):

    final_df = pd.DataFrame()

    self.multiprocessing_test_run()

    for file in os.listdir(data_dir)[:200]:
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df, pd.read_csv(data_dir + file)], axis=0)
    self.data_day = final_df

    self.multiprocessing_test_run()
```

Comment: Is it possible the bottleneck is on your hard drive rather than RAM/CPU? do you use a SSD? Could you share the implementation of your pg_data_download_run? is it possible there's blocking IO in there?

Comment: Hard drive has 60 GB free, I am using an SSD.  the pg_data_download_run simply downloads data via RESTful API and writes out a file to disk, nothing loaded to RAM.  If I run the pg_data_download_run back to back it executes in the same amount of time, so I think that rules out any issues with that function- I have also written test functions to drop in place of pg_data_download_run and have seen similar degradation.

Comment: how big are these API calls? you could be bounded by the network connection. Try using something like vcrpy to record the requests, and eliminates the need to send API request, then compare the time again. Or you could try the python profiler to see what your program spent the most time doing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Comment: I updated my initial question to include dummy functions with no API calls and I have the same issue, so I think we can eliminate that option.  Let me know if you can re-create my issue with this code?  I can take a look at the profiler but I know it is taking the most time on the second function already, what i am not sure is why the multiprocessing tasks are not being created/executed efficiently.